# Saving user input in Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, save

I am new to Visual C#, and I can't find the answer to my question anywhere.  I have a program that has a couple of lists (of pictureboxes) and an array (of strings), that their value is changed according to the user's input. I want to put a function that will allow the user to save the information in the lists, so that he may reopen his application later on.  How and where do I save the information in my lists and pictureboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are new i'll just Explain what Tom said :

you may add a button to your form with name : Save , when clicked it will save the array string to a .txt file, that will be loaded in the same array in form load Event!!

for saving :

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("info.txt", yourarray);
```

for loading, in the form load event :

```
if(File.Exisis("info.txt"))
        {
           var TextLines = File.ReadAllLines("info.txt");
           foreach (var line in TextLines)
         {
           yourarray.Add(line);
         }
        }
```

Note : your array should be generic..

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. If I want to save a matrix, how do I do that?  I really appreciate that you explained it to me.

Comment: that would be a bit harder and more complicated !! to ways to do this: 1-save all data in a line with a separator after each info (info1,info2). 2-using XML file for each pic box one Node contains it's data ..

Comment: How do I save all the data in a line?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the data to disk somewhere (either just in a file or in a database etc.) if you want to keep the state between application runs.

Then when you start up the application you want to check wherever you saved this information to see if there is data from a previous application run. If there is data, you can then load it in, otherwise start from a fresh state.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open question in that there are numerous ways in which you could accomplish this.

The most straight forward method is by storing the images locally and then loading them with a load function that rebuilds your list/array

This(and other resources on the MSDN) might be of help to you, specifically this one:[Image.Save Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

There is also this if you'd like to approach this using a database: [How to Save and Load Image from Database in C# desktop application](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/655721/Csharp-Save-and-Load-Image-from-Database)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I don't only want to save the images, I want to save the location of all the pictureboxes, the tags that were placed, and basically all the information stored in the object. Do you know how to do that? Should I use XML serialization?

Comment: Yes if you want the entire list structure/object saved you will have to use something more complicated like XML. OR go with the database and chug through field after field for each type of data you need for each one.